# Laravel: REJECT ROUTE not defined but exists in web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-routing, laravel-route

I have a reject function in my Calendar controller but whenever I redirect to the view page it displays an error saying my route is not defined.

I've tried rearranging and renaming my route but it's still displaying the error.

Here is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('therapist.reject.appointment', $bookingRequest), 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'javascript:return confirm("Are you sure?")']) !!}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Reject this appointment</button>
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here are my routes. The other routes displayed are working perfectly:

```
Route::get('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}', 'TherapistCalander')->name('therapist.calendar');

    Route::post('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}',
        'TherapistCalander@saveAppointment')->name('therapist.book.appointment');

    Route::patch('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}', 
        'TherapistCalander@finishedAppointment')->name('therapist.finish.appointment');

    Route::delete('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}',
    'TherapistCalander@rejectAppointment')->name('therapist.reject.appointment');

    Route::delete('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}', 
        'TherapistCalander@cancelAppointment')->name('therapist.cancel.appointment');
```

And lastly, my function:

```
public function rejectAppointment(Request $request, BookingRequest $bookingRequest)
    {
        $bookingRequest->reject();

        return redirect()->back()->with('rejectStatus', true);
    }
```

The view page where this button belongs should be able to display the buttons for rejecting and finishing, alongside the calendar view.

**EDIT**
Follow up question: Is it possibly because the routes are similar to one another? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using all the tagged versions of Laravel? If not, then can you update the question tags?

Comment: Also, you should look into resource routes - this would make your routing a bit simpler and handle some boilerplate work.

Comment: @Adam sorry for that! Edited :D

Comment: Is it possible to use resource routes even if i'm not using a resource controller?

Comment: Yes. A resource controller is just a standard way of naming each function - you can replicate part (or all) of that without creating it via `php artisan make:controller --resource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**PROBLEM FIXED**

I realized since they have similar links, web.php found it confusing so it did not read this route.

That is why I changed my route from:

```
  Route::delete('therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}',
'TherapistCalander@rejectAppointment')->name('therapist.reject.appointment');
```

To this:

```
Route::delete('doReject/{bookingRequest}',
    'TherapistCalander@rejectAppointment')->name('therapist.reject.appointment');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the Reject and Cancel the url string because it is similar.

```
Route::delete(
    'therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}/delete',
    'TherapistCalander@rejectAppointment'
)->name('therapist.reject.appointment');

Route::delete(
    'therapist-calendar/{bookingRequest}', 
    'TherapistCalander@cancelAppointment'
)->name('therapist.cancel.appointment');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
    {!! Form::open(['url' => route('therapist.reject.appointment', ['bookingRequest' => $bookingRequest]), 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'javascript:return confirm("Are you sure?")']) !!}
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Reject this appointment</button>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The route parameters are passed as an array and that should work fine. Refer [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

Can you try this code

```
<form action="{{ route('therapist.reject.appointment', ['bookingRequest' => $bookingRequest]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Reject this appointment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to pass an array for a single parameter in the route.

Comment: @jogesh_pi it will be a great help to add the reference link that descibe your point for me as well as future visitors, can you please add a reference link to doc?

Comment: @DanielaEchavez Can you try the new code, I have posted and tell me the new result/error you will get?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I changed the link. I was only able to see your post after I posted an update. But thank you!

Comment: @DanielaEchavez no problem friend, more important is to solve the problem in proper way and not through work around, if you got a solution, it is always good.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Hope this will help you https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_route